# Create new variables based on number from file - C

Tags: c, variables, struct

My assignment is to create an invoice based on input information from a file.

I have everything working well but it is based on the prior knowledge I have of the number of different people in the input file (i.e. 2 "customers" = I made 2 structs).

My question is this: how can I take the number of customers given (in the first line of the input file) and use it to create that number of separate structs.

> Example: I read in "2" from the first line, and create 2 structs.
>
> Example: I read in "4" from the first line, and create 4 structs.

I know this is a pretty simple solution using a loop of some sort, counting until it reaches said number from first line, but how would I create/initialize the correct number of new structs?

An example I tried was something along the lines of:

```
while(j<numOrders){
customer c[j];
j++;
}
```

using the logic that when `j=2` then `customer c2` would be created. I realize this is incorrect, but am unsure of how to solve this dilemma.

Here is the rest of my code just so y'all can see what I have going so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct it{
    char name[15];
    float weight;
    float price;
}item;

typedef struct c{
    char first[10];
    char last[15];
    int numProducts;
    item itemList[10]; 
}customer;

//customer createCustomer(int numOrders, FILE *input);
int main(){


    FILE *input = fopen("invoice1.txt","r");

    int numOrders, i=0,j=0;
    customer c1,c2;
    item i1;

    fscanf(input,"%d",&numOrders);
    fscanf(input,"%s %s",&c1.first, &c1.last);
    fscanf(input,"%d",&c1.numProducts);
    printf("%d\n%s %s %d\n",numOrders, c1.first, c1.last,c1.numProducts);
        //while loop here
    while (i<c1.numProducts){
    fscanf(input,"%s %f %f", &c1.itemList[i].name, &c1.itemList[i].price, &c1.itemList[i].weight);
    printf("%s %.2f %.2f\n",c1.itemList[i].name,c1.itemList[i].price,c1.itemList[i].weight);
    i++;
    }

    fscanf(input,"%s %s %d",&c2.first, &c2.last,&c2.numProducts);
    printf("%s %s %d\n", c2.first, c2.last,c2.numProducts);

    while (j<c2.numProducts){
    fscanf(input,"%s %f %f", &c2.itemList[j].name, &c2.itemList[j].price, &c2.itemList[j].weight);
    printf("%s %.2f %.2f\n",c2.itemList[j].name,c2.itemList[j].price,c2.itemList[j].weight);
    j++;
    }

    //  c1 = createCustomer(numOrders, input);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You need to use dynamic initialization.

Comment: What do you mean by 2/4 structs?

Comment: @Sohaib basically I would read in the number "2" and then the information given for 2 different customers. But, this number of customers could change, so what I have so far: `c1` and `c2` only works because I know there are 2 customers in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a pointer to an array of customers. Dynamic Initialization would help. Something along these lines:

```
customer *listOfCustomers;
fscanf(input,"%d",&numberOfCustomers);
listOfCustomers = (customer*)malloc(sizeof(customer)*numberOfCustomers);
```

Then you can access this listOfCustomers as

```
int i=0;
while(i<numberOfCustomers){
    //Do Something with listOfCustomers[i]
}
```

If you are sure that the numberOfCustomers are small you could use a static array instead of a pointer.

```
#define N 50
customer listOfCustomers[N]
```

The method for accessing the listOfCustomers remains the same.

> EDIT: How to use arrays in this case

Using the loops we wrote above we write this as:

```
//we declare the pointer to customer c in the same manner as explained above.
customer *c;
fscanf(input,"%d",&numberOfCustomers);
c = (customer*)malloc(sizeof(customer)*numberOfCustomers);
while(i<numberOfCustomers){
    fscanf(input,"%s %s",&c[i].first, &c[i].last);
    fscanf(input,"%d",&c[i].numProducts);
    //while loop here
    int j=0;
    while (j<c[i].numProducts){
        fscanf(input,"%s %f %f", &c[i].itemList[j].name, &c1.itemList[j].price, &c[i].itemList[j].weight);
        j++;
    }
    i++
}
//Then for printing the customer information we use a similar loop
i=0;
while(i<numberOfCustomers){
    printf("FirstName: %s LastName: %s",c[i].first, c[i].last);
    int j=0;
    while (j<c[i].numProducts){
        printf(input,"%s %f %f", c[i].itemList[j].name, c1.itemList[j].price, c[i].itemList[j].weight);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Feel free to ask if you need more details.

Comment: thank you!!!! I guess I am still a bit confused about exactly how this all is being saved. Like, how would I go about creating the number of customer structs based on this?

Comment: You don't need to create a number of customer structs. You just need to create an array. Read about arrays: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm

Comment: I say this with no condescension at all, just trying to figure it out  and learn - I have a decent grasp on arrays and my assignment calls for structs (probably should have added that in the OP). How would I make the array work correctly in this circumstance?

Comment: @bravesaint I have added in an example way just copying your code. A similar loops could be written out for printing the listOfCustomers ie, `c`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error I was getting before: `"c" undefined (first use in this function)`

Comment: @bravesaint You need declare the array first. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first take input as number of customers then use a loop to take information of all the customers and store them where you want.

Comment: I need to print out the information **after** the entire file has been read through and saved. I apologize, should have mentioned that in the OP. I take that as needing to save the information of each iteration of the loop into a separate struct. Wouldn't running all that in a loop simply re-write the struct I had previously made? Thank you!

Comment: You need to make array of structure and store customer information in it. Simply make a struct and make array of it.